# Converting a list to it's separate entities in Racket?

Tags: list, racket

How do you convert a list of numbers to it's separate entities within Racket without using recursion?

For example, I would like to convert (list 1 2 3 4) into its separate numbers of 1 2 3 4, so I can add all the entities together giving me 1+2+3+4 = 10.

Comment: What you want is `apply`. You have a function, `+`, which takes multiple arguments (not as a list, but as separate arguments), you have a list, and you want to apply the function to the elements of that list. That's exactly what `apply` does. `(apply + (list 1 2 3 4))` is equivalent to `(+ 1 2 3 4)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Breaking a list into its separate entities” does not really make *that much* sense, given that those numbers have to be stored somewhere. When you write a definition, you bind a *value* to a *name*, like this:

```
(define x 7)
```

But when you have a list, you have *multiple values*, so in order to break the list into individual pieces, you would need *multiple names*. If your list will always be the same length, this isn’t impossible—you could use functions like `first`, `second`, `third`, and so on to extract individual values:

```
(define lst '(1 2 3))

(define a (first lst))
(define b (second lst))
(define c (third lst))
```

However, lists are not usually used this way, and in most cases, the list could be of any length. Therefore, it’s impossible to know what names to give the values ahead of time because the number of names needed is not necessarily known when the program is written! Therefore, you don’t want to “break the list up”, what you *really* want to do is operate on the whole list at once.

---

The most primitive way to operate on a whole list at once is to use recursion explicitly, but most of the time, there are *recursive patterns* that come up so often, there are existing functions to do the same thing without writing all the boilerplate. For example, `map` applies a function to each element of a list, and `filter` selects elements from a list that satisfy a predicate. For your question, though, you don’t want either of those things: you want to collect all elements of a list together to produce a single value.

The concept of “collecting elements” in functional programming is called a **fold**, and Racket provides the [`foldl`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29) (“left fold”) function to do precisely that. You provide a function to collect with, in your case `+`, a “zero value”, which will be used as the starting accumulator, and the list to collect up. In this case, the “zero value” is just the number `0`, since zero is the additive identity:

```
(define (sum lst)
  (foldl + 0 lst))

> (sum '(1 2 3))
6
```

---

Folds are a very general way to collect elements of a list. However, as [Alex Knauth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5432501/alex-knauth) mentions, Scheme provides another way for simpler cases: since `+` in Scheme can accept any number of arguments, it implicitly does a sort of fold if you provide it more than two numbers:

```
> (+ 1 2 3)
6
```

To invoke a function with a set of arguments as a list, not as separate values, you can use [`apply`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/application.html#%28part._apply%29), which accepts a function and a list as arguments:

```
(define (sum lst)
  (apply + lst))
```

This is the idiomatic way to perform a simple sum of a list of numbers in Scheme and Racket.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is [`apply`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/application.html#%28part._apply%29):

```
> (apply + (list 1 2 3 4))
10
```

You have a function, `+`, which takes multiple arguments (not as a list, but as separate arguments). You want to apply this function to the elements of a list, with each element of the list being a separate argument to pass in. That's exactly what [`apply`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/application.html#%28part._apply%29) does.

An [`apply`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/application.html#%28part._apply%29) call like

```
(apply + (list 1 2 3 4))
```

Is equivalent to

```
(+ 1 2 3 4)
```

The major advantage of [`apply`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/application.html#%28part._apply%29) is that it works on computed lists, not just hard-coded `(list ...)` forms, so it also works on [`append`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._append%29%29)ed lists:

```
> (apply + (append (list 1 2 3 4) (list 2 3 4)))
19
```

And lists that come from function arguments, as [Alexis King's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38537660/converting-a-list-to-its-separate-entities-in-racket/38537731#38537731) mentions:

```
> (define (sum lst)
    (apply + lst))
> (sum (list 1 2 3 4))
10
> (sum (append (list 1 2 3 4) (list 2 3 4)))
19
```

Comment: so if i wanted to add the entities of two lists, i would do something like this:(apply + (list  1 2 3 4) (list 2 3 4)) to get 1+2+3+4+2+3+4 = 19?

Comment: No, for that you would want `(apply + (append (list 1 2 3 4) (list 2 3 4)))`.

Answer (score 0):

Convert a list of numbers to it's separate entities. If you know the length you can use accessors:

```scm
(define lst '(1 2 3 4))
(+ (first lst) (second lst) (third lst) (fourth lst)) ; ==> 10
```

`first`, `second`, ... resides in `racket/list` and in the `#!racket` language. They are aliases for the more general cxr accessors:

```scm
(+ (car lst) (cadr lst) (caddr lst) (cadddr lst)) ; ==> 10
```

If you have a list `lst` which you know is reasonable small, less than a 200 elements, you can use `apply` to give them all as arguments and even give additional arguments in front:

```scm
(apply + lst)   ; ==> 10
(apply + 5 lst) ; ==> 15
```

There is a symmetry between rest arguments and apply, thus one might think of them as oposites:

```scm
(define (prefix-zero . xs)
  (apply list 0 xs))

(prefix-zero 1 2 3) ; ==> (0 1 2 3)
```

For larger lists you can use `foldl`, that does two and two down to one value starting with the second argument as intermediate value:

```scm
(foldl + 0 lst) ; ==> 10
```

`foldl` is implemented using recursion and it does + starting with 0 with each elements so it works as:

```scm
(+ (cadddr lst) (+ (caddr lst) (+ (cadr lst) (+ 0 (car lst))))) ; ==> 10
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you may be interested in quasiquote function as well.

The uses are more versatile, but an example to show how it works:

When you have a list, say

```
(define list1 (list 5 6 7))
```

then you can create another list:

```
(define list2 `(1 2 3 4 ,@list1))
(define list3 `(1 2 3 4 ,list1))
```

or

```
(define list2 (quasiquote (1 2 3 4 (unquote-splicing list1))))
(define list3 (quasiquote (1 2 3 4 (unquote list1))))
> list2
'(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
> list3
'(1 2 3 4 (5 6 7))
```